# How to capture traffic from a website using tcpdump

Tags: linux, networking, tcpdump

I need to capture traffic to https://gmail.com using tcpdump. I solved this by using `tcpdump -n dst host <ipaddress of gmail>` But is there any way I can directly specify gmail.com instead of the ipaddress so that it will capture the traffic to https://gmail.com.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you should definitely use

```
tcpdump -n dst host gmail.com
```

instead of

```
tcpdump -n dst host <ipaddress of gmail>
```

. This is because `gmail.com` has multiple IP addresses (I count 5 from my point of view: 4 v4 and 1 v6) and giving the name to the filter will automatically match all of them. Otherwise you have to specify a much longer filter that includes all of the addresses, such as this:

```
tcpdump -n host <ip1> or host <ip2> or host <ip3> [...]
```

Note: You have `dst` in your filter which will cause you to match only packets whose destination is gmail. That means you will capture only half the stream. Is that really what you want?